# In Laravel, should I make different view files or add switch case in view file?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have to show list of posts in a view. Functions in controller query posts and send them to view. Functions like drafts(), pending(), published() etc will query posts for related status.

All view layout would almost be same other than page title and buttons that appear alongside each post.

So my confusion is, should I make individual view file like drafts.blade.php, pending.blade.php, published.blade.php, etc and have logic less static buttons & page title
OR
instead use one single view like posts-list.blade.php and use switch case or something to bring up buttons and title based on status of the post.

Thank you,

=======

## UPDATE

I added a [serviceprovider](http://pastebin.com/gttYqsd3) to extend blade functionality. Now I can use [@switch($var), @case(1), @break](http://pastebin.com/C8mCriKg) etc in view.

Comment: you should make different view. make a layout with common feature in all page and implement this layout in all view

Comment: Thanks @Md.SahadatHossain. I did think about that but I don't think it's quite doable the scenario I'm working on. Please kindly have a look at this [paste](http://pastebin.com/JJkvCH5R). may be code explains better than I did above.

Answer (score 0):

actually there's nothing completely true or wrong. in case like yours I'd ask myself about how different is these required views  if there's alot of differences I'll separate them and if No I'll just make one view with parameters to bass. like:

posts-list.blade.php

```
<h1>{{ $title }}</h1>
@if( $pageType == 'draft' )
    // show button1
@elseif( $pageType == 'pending')
    // show button2
@elseif( $pageType == 'published')
    // show button3
@else
    // default
@endif
```

and in calling it I'll just use `return view('posts-list.blade.php', ['title ' => 'Awesome page', 'pageType' => 'pending']);`
again it depends on how complex the differences are.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean whatever I've done [here](http://pastebin.com/JJkvCH5R) is not as bad as I think it is. I know it's not a big deal but just trying to know if this is totally okay to go with.

Comment: When doing few searches, I came to land on few articles which state there should not be business logic things in view file. This is what bothering me with my implementation.

Comment: ok, the thing is you're not doing any logic related thing here. there's no processing, calculations for short data won't change in the view. you'll just control what to show depending on the given data

Comment: in many cases-really many- you'll be forced to do use `@if` and similar in blade that's why it's built in laravel
have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#control-structures

Comment: @Prajwol after looking at your code it's ok with one comment from my side. You've used `<?php ?>` which isn't the best practice in laravel. after working for two years with laravel 4, 5.1, .2, .3, .4 I've never had to use it. make your code more LARAVELY convert this `switch case` to `@if @ifelse @endif` that way your code is likely to be more cleaner as a blade. try this http://pastebin.com/MFSD6K4f

Comment: Thanks. I'd have definitely gone with if elseif there were less number of case check. But for the number of cases I've right now, I really think I need to go with switch case. Hence, I added a serviceprovider to extend blade functionality. Now I can use @switch($var), @case(1), @break etc. Service Provider [here](http://pastebin.com/gttYqsd3) & view file [here](http://pastebin.com/C8mCriKg). I hope I didn't overkill. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: Greate, if this @switch($var) part is going to grow over this you can put it in a partial to make this page view more readable

Comment: Agreed. Will do if need be. Thanks.